# JSON property value change on event and get it globaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to get sales value out of the console as per the changes of month and i want that data should be affect my data
here is my select box:

```
<select id="months">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="nov">NOV</option>
  <option value="dec">DEC</option>
  <option value="jan">JAN</option>
</select>
```

this is JavaScript

```
  function sales(booked, total) {
    this.booked = booked;
    this.total = total;
  };

  sale = new sales(8, 12) ;

  $("#months").on('change', function(){
    mons = $(this).val();
    console.log(mons);

    if(mons == "nov"){
      sale = new sales(1,12) ;
    }

    if(mons == "dec"){
      sale = new sales(2,12) ;
    }

    if(mons == "jan"){
      sale = new sales(15,12) ;
    }   
    console.log(sale.booked +' ' +sale.total);
  });

  console.log(sale.booked +' ' +sale.total);



  var w = 400;
  var h = 400;
  var r = h/2;
  var color = d3.scale.category20c();

  data = [{"label":"booked " + sale.booked, "value": sale.booked}, 
                    {"label": "total " + sale.total, "value": sale.total}];

  var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
  var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){return d.value;});

  // declare an arc generator function
  var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

  // select paths, use arc generator to draw
  var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
  arcs.append("svg:path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i){
          return color(i);
      })
      .attr("d", function (d) {
          // log the result of the arc generator to show how cool it is :)
          //console.log(arc(d));
          return arc(d);
      });
```

I want to change value of var data as per the change of this months select box,
i am trying to get this through this but within the scope of month change function it works fine and values are getting changed but outside i cannot get that changes.
How can i get that.

Comment: `sales.total` evaluates value of the `total` key hence even later in the life cycle of the application, `data` object will not be updated..

Comment: Code looks fine to me.

Comment: try removing `var` before `sales`... or share rest code;

Comment: no its not working this way, the code is getting change inside change event functions scope but i cannot retrieve those changes outside that function,

Comment: Why dont you initialize the var outside the function and set it inside the function? Correct me if I misunderstood your question

Comment: i tried that with simple object and then i update that inside function but out of that function values are not getting change, it only effects inside that function, but outside that its same, i have to handle select box event and also that value, if i try to put every thing inside that function then its creating three time same graph

Comment: Can you possibly add a plunkr?

Comment: i didn't understand, what is this plunkr.

Comment: @Ganpat Kakar http://plnkr.co/